# Cant delete picture with ACTION_PICK using google photos

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to delete a image from the gallery after using Intent.ACTION PICK. my code works ok when i dont use google photos to select the picture. i already ask for the permissions in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my fun with the intent:

```
fun selectPhoto(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        val intentOnResult = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intentOnResult.type = "image/*"
        intentOnResult.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        startActivityForResult(intentOnResult,0)
    }else{
        requestStoragePermissions()
    }
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
        contentResolver.delete(intent.data!!,null,null)
        pictureloaded = true
    }

}
```

but i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224
flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list
U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224}
}} to activity
{com.maxiarce.habitstracker/com.maxiarce.habitstracker.AddHabitActivity}:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider
uri
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224
from pid=9348, uid=10085 requires the provider be exported, or
grantUriPermission()
```

i couldnt find any answer that solve my issue. Sorry if im not clear im kind of new, Thanks!

Comment: where is your `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission ?

Comment: I tried adding it , but same error.